# How to cast to a variable type - emulating type variables in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-conversion

I am implementing something similar to a typed genetic programming and have become a little stuck with regards to C++ types.

I have a network of nodes, nodes have different types, for example some are functional nodes whereas others are just data.  In order to deal with collections of such nodes, I saw no option other than to use polymoprphism to store colection of base class pointers.

```
class Node {
private:
    std::string label;
    std::string node_type;
};

template
<typename FNC>
class FunctionalNode : public Node {
    std::function<FNC> function;
};

class Network {
   std::vector<Node*> nodes;
   ...
}
```

Note I have a templated `FunctionalNode`, which stores a `std::function`, I think (but am not certain) that my problem applies equally if I were to store a plain function pointer instead.

So the problem is, at some point given a `Node` pointer to a dervied `FunctionalNode`, I need to apply the stored function to some values.  This means I need to cast the base pointer onto the derived class, but since it is templated I am not sure how to do this.

I would like to do something like the following fake C++ code, which would need something like type variables:

```
Node * applyfunction(Node * functional_node, std::vector<Node*> arguments) {
    typevariable function_type = convert_node_type_to_typevariable(functional_node.node_type)
    functional_node_derived * = static_cast<function_type>(functional_node);
    ....
}
```

Where a node's `node_type` is some structure I use to contain the type information of the node, e.g. the type of its functional form, and `convert_node_type_to_typevariable` would convert this to a typevariable I can use in this hypothetical C++ language.

Any ideas how I could implementing this seing as C++ lacks support for type variables, or a completely different approach to the problem?

Comment: fair enough, tell me where I can improve and be more precise.

Comment: E.g. you could provide a minimal compiling code example that displays a concrete error or problem that you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exploit your polymorphic structure. You can define `Node` with a pure virtual method instead of making `applyfunction` a free function.

```
class Node {
protected:
    std::string label;
    std::string node_type;
public:
    virtual ~Node () {}
    virtual Node * applyfunction (std::vector<Node *> args) = 0;
};
```

Then your derivations would perform the work.

```
template
<typename FNC>
class FunctionalNode : public Node {
    std::function<FNC> function;
public:
    Node * applyfunction (std::vector<Node *> args) {
        //...
    }
};
```